# Error using when using malloc for 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

Why does this show a warning for dereferencing nullptr in C

```
Level1Tilemap->Map = (int*)((malloc(Level1Columns * sizeof(int))));

for (int i = 0; i < Level1Columns; i++)
{
    Level1Tilemap->Map[i] = malloc(Level1Rows * sizeof(int));

    for (int j = 0; j < Level1Rows; j++)
    {
        Level1Tilemap->Map[i][j] = Level1MapStaticArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

I am using malloc to create a 2D array of ints

But the editor shows warning and Level1Tilemap->Map has the memory address of nullptr

And the defination  int** Map;

Comment: At a guess your editor is simply warning you that `malloc` can return a null pointer and you should check for that

Comment: In the first allocation, you use `sizeof(int)` but you probably want `sizeof(int*)`

Comment: Probably not your issue, but you want `(int*)((malloc(Level1Columns * sizeof(int))));` -> `(int*)((malloc(Level1Columns * sizeof(int*))));`

Comment: Check for malloc returning `NULL`, and if it does, use `perror()` to print it.

Comment: Is your `Level1Tilemap` properly set to something? And is it `Level1Tilemap->Map = (int**)malloc...` you want?

Answer (score 2):

You might have meant to use a pointer-to-pointer, in which case `sizeof(int)` should have been `sizeof(int*)`. However, don't do that, it's obscure and slow, for no good reason.

Instead do

```
size_t size = sizeof(int[Level1Columns][Level1Rows]);

int (*something)[Level1Rows] = malloc(size);
if(something == NULL) { /* error handling */ }

memcpy(something, Level1MapStaticArray, size);
...
free(something);
```

Apart from reducing code complexity, this will significantly outperform the code you have currently.

Answer (score -1):

```c
// map is an array of (int*), and the length is column
int** map = (int**) malloc(column * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < column; ++i) {
    // map[i] is an array of int, and the length is row
    map[i] = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));

    for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
        map[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: You fixed the first malloc call and broke the second one instead...

Comment: Anyway, there is no sensible reason why you would ever want to use a fragmented malloc like this, when dealing with a plain 2D int array.